# How to customize the no of line codes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, onclick, carousel

**How to customize the no of line codes in jQuery?**

Actually on click event the particular Bootstrap carousel image has to show on below section/div with data slide dots highlighted. Thanks in advance.

I got the result but I feel like below jQuery can be customized. Can any help or advise how it can be...

```
$("#usaGrown-slide").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    //alert("Handler");
    $("#usaGrown-slide1").addClass('active');
    $("#spinning-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#knitting-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#dyeing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#cutsew-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#embellishing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#packaging-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#distribution-slide1").removeClass('active');
});
$("#spinning-slide").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#usaGrown-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#spinning-slide1").addClass('active');
    $("#knitting-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#dyeing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#cutsew-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#embellishing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#packaging-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#distribution-slide1").removeClass('active');
});
$("#knitting-slide").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#usaGrown-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#spinning-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#knitting-slide1").addClass('active');
    $("#dyeing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#cutsew-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#embellishing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#packaging-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#distribution-slide1").removeClass('active');
});
$("#dyeing-slide").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#usaGrown-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#spinning-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#knitting-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#dyeing-slide1").addClass('active');
    $("#cutsew-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#embellishing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#packaging-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#distribution-slide1").removeClass('active');
});
$("#cutsew-slide").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#usaGrown-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#spinning-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#knitting-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#dyeing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#cutsew-slide1").addClass('active');
    $("#embellishing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#packaging-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#distribution-slide1").removeClass('active');
});
$("#embellishing-slide").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#usaGrown-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#spinning-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#knitting-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#dyeing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#cutsew-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#embellishing-slide1").addClass('active');
    $("#packaging-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#distribution-slide1").removeClass('active');
});
$("#packaging-slide").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#usaGrown-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#spinning-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#knitting-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#dyeing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#cutsew-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#embellishing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#packaging-slide1").addClass('active');
    $("#distribution-slide1").removeClass('active');
});
$("#distribution-slide").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#usaGrown-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#spinning-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#knitting-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#dyeing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#cutsew-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#embellishing-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#packaging-slide1").removeClass('active');
    $("#distribution-slide1").addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: whats a "no of line " lol man :))?

Comment: btw i like how DRY is your code

Comment: 1) We need to see your HTML to help you effectively 2) You should research the DRY principle

Answer (score 0):

No need to write same block of code for multiple Jquery Id Selector. You can do this by comma separator like this.

```
  $("#usaGrown-slide,#spinning-slide,#dyeing-slide,#cutsew-slide").click(function () {
      $("#usaGrown-slide1,#spinning-slide1,#dyeing-slide1,#cutsew-slide1").removeClass('active');
      $(this+'1').addClass('active');
  });
```